# Color in Console Application

Tags: vb.net, colors, console-application

So I'm working on a console based application in visual basic and I ran into a problem. I am trying add color to the console but only to 1 word within the line. I know the `Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red` option but that color's the whole line not 1 word in the line. I will provide some examples below.

Here is some sample code:

```
'If I use it like this the whole line will turn red
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
Console.WriteLine("Hello stackoverflow, I need some help!")
```

As said above, The whole line turn's red. What if I only want the word "stackoverflow" to be red and the rest of the sentence to stay the normal color?

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Console.Write("Hello ");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.Write("stackoverflow");
Console.ResetColor();
Console.WriteLine(", I need some help!");
```

You might want to tokenize your string and use some kind of pattern matching function to build something reusable.

color a single word in string (add logic to handle commas and periods):

```
private static void colorize(string expression, string word) 
{
    string[] substrings = expression.Split();

    foreach (string substring in substrings)
    {
        if (substring.Contains(word))
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        }
        Console.Write(substring+" ");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Aha, I am truly stupid. Can't believe I forgot about Console.Write(). Thanks!

Comment: What's this tokenizing thing you talk about?

Comment: use a regular expression to split the string,then color the matches. I'll post an update in a sec for you. in the meantime, can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a string list and a color list. The first string in the string list gets the first color from the color list and so on.

```
Sub Write(ByRef strings As IEnumerable(Of String), ByRef colors As IEnumerable(Of ConsoleColor))
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each s In strings
        Console.ForegroundColor = colors(i)
        Console.Write(s)
        i += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Example:

```
Write({"Hello ", "stackoverflow, ", "i ", "need ", "some ", "help "}, {Red, Green, Yellow, Magenta, Gray, Cyan})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Shared Sub colorize(ByVal expression As String, ByVal word As String)
    Dim substrings() As String = expression.Split()

    For Each substring As String In substrings
        If substring.Contains(word) Then
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
        End If
        Console.Write(substring &" ")
        Console.ResetColor()
    Next substring
    Console.WriteLine()
End Sub
```